# .htaccess RewriteRule not working in different host

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

My Current .htaccess rule's example

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)-([0-9]+) my_article.php?article_permalink=$1&article_id=$2 [NC,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404errorpage.php
```

**Output:**
https://example.com/my-article-example-1

**In my localhost and current host these rules working fine. But in other host**

10 day ago when I had changed my hosting the first rules was not working. it's showing 404 page (returns 404).

**Today in new host the second rule ErrorDocument not working. It's showing**

> Not Found
> The requested URL was not found on this server.
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
> use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

**Expected output:**
for any 404 error show 404errorpage page

Now I can't understand what is the problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your code in your question. Please do let us know path of your htaccess and php file?

Comment: path of .htaccess and 404errorpage is root folder

Comment: How about my_article.php file present?

Comment: my_article.php also in root folder

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess Rules. Please make sure your htaccess rules file, my_articile.php file both are in same folder(root folder). Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(\d+)/?$  /my_article.php?article_permalink=$1&article_id=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404errorpage.php
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Now using another hosting service and I am saving your RewriteRule in my htaccess file as comment. When I will face the same 404 issue in my_article.php page I will use this definitely. But now, my ErrorDocument 404 not working. It's not showing 404errorpage.php page as 404 page. It's showing "Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server. Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Comment: @YeasherArafath, is your 404errorpage.php present along with your htacess file?

Comment: Yes. .htaccess and 404errorpage.php in same folder